# Script to keep alive FTP/SFTP sessions over gvfs

Tags: ftp, gvfs

I want my FTP/SFTP sessions kept alive when I use my file browser (PCmanfm).
There are some bash scripts out there to achieve this goal.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Ubuntu closes FTP connections after a few idle minutes
# This script keeps all mounted FTP connections alive

while true 
do
 ls ~/.gvfs/FTP* &> /dev/null
 sleep 60
done
```

So I made this script executable

```
sudo chmod +x /home/username/.config/gvfs-keep-alive
```

then I added it to the rc.local file.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
/home/username/.config/gvfs-keep-alive
exit 0
```

But it blocks my computer during reboot and I have to get into recovery mode 
to remove the line from rc.local and reboot again.

- Is this script correct ?
- If it is, where should I put it to make the keep alive process functional ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The script is sort of correct. However,it contains an infinite loop and never exits.

When ubuntu boots, it calls this script from rc.local, and because it never exits, rc.local never finishes and the computer never finishes the boot.

Given you want to execute the command every minute, you could simply create an entry in /etc/crontab, something like:

```
* * * * *   username    ls /home/username/.gvfs/FTP* >/dev/null
```

Depending on personal preference, you could also create a systemd service to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Indeed it couldn't work. 
Run it as a service sounds good, I'll see how to achieve this.

Regarding the script it turns out that gvfs folder location has changed since Ubuntu 14.04
So to have the script running properly just replace: 

`ls ~/.gvfs/FTP* &> /dev/null`

with:

`ls /run/user/$UID/gvfs/FTP* &> /dev/null`